# Should I provide a setter for @Autowired

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring 3.0.x with my project.
My current practice with `@Autowired` is exemplified as follows:

```
 @Autowired
 private SomeType someMemberVariable;
```

Is the use of a setter method better and/or preferred?  By setter, I mean the following:

```
 private SomeType someMemberVariable;

 @Autowired
 private void setSomeMemberVariable(SomeType newValue)
 {
  someMemberVariable = newValue;
 }
```

I understand mutable vs immutable setters, that is out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not using a setter when using `@Autowired` - it adds boilerplate code.

Whenever I need to set a dependency in a unit test, I use `ReflectionTestUtils.setField(..)` - it is not compile-time safe as a setter, but I haven't got much trouble with it.

As a sidenote, if using spring 3.0, you can start using `@Inject` instead of `@Autowired`

Comment: I suspect that @Inject only works for Java 6.0 and higher.  If still using Java 5.0 (perhaps because you are using WAS 6.1), @Autowired is the way to go.

Comment: @Inject would work if you have it on the classpath. You can get it from here https://code.google.com/p/atinject/ I'm using it on tomcat.

Comment: Why `@Inject` over `@Autowired`? Any reference?

Comment: one is spring-specific, the other is kind of more standard.. no other reason

Answer (score 16):

I prefer using setters and getters because it allows you to manually wire up the object when you're not running it in a Spring context (i.e., setting mocks in a unit test).